# Azure DevOps Workflow Rules

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to create a flow rule in AzDO where when a user transitions a work item from one state to another, AzDO will require the use to add a comment.  I'm able to configure this in Jira, but haven't found a way to create this rule in AzDO.  Has anyone run into this and solved it?

Answer (score 0):

If there was a way to do this, it would be using [workflow rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/apply-rules-to-workflow-states?view=azure-devops).  That being said, it doesn't appear like the discussion field is something that can be required.